# Are inchoative and causative verbs action or stative verbs?

Tags: verbs

Dears, 
I have searched for this question and I haven't found any information about it. Are inchoative and causative verbs action or stative verbs?

Thanks

Comment: They both signal changes. How are you defining 'action' and 'stative' verbs? Have you an article listing some? I'd say the crude dichotomy fails here. Verbs like 'start [to V]' are really functional; it's the 'V' that fits better into your classification. In a colligation such as 'go shopping' there is a phase structure, where I'd not class the two words separately.  Causitive verbs don't always relate to physical action (at an observable level, at any rate).

Comment: This might be better asked over on [linguistics.se] as it is not specific to English. That said, can you give examples of all four: inchoative, causative, action, and stative?

Comment: https://www.englishgrammar.org/state-verbs-action-verbs/.

Comment: Mitch: Stative verb: understand, action verb: run inchoative verb: start, causative verb: get

Comment: It's, like, complicated. There are several different kinds of active and stative verbs. Inchoative and causative is a different dimension with different combinations, and different senses, depending on the predicates involved. Most causatives are active, but the same verb can often be either inchoative or causative; further, repetitive or generic actions can be interpreted as states, and physical states can be interpreted as events and actions.

Comment: Dears?.........

Answer (score 3):

It's, like, complicated. There are several different kinds of active and stative verbs.

Inchoative and causative is a different dimension with different combinations, and different senses, depending on the predicates involved. Most causatives are active, but the same verb can often be either inchoative or causative; further, repetitive or generic actions can be interpreted as states, and physical states can be interpreted as events and actions. –
*John Lawler*